# Vuepress dev server is not working when only i tried it by yarn

Tags: vuepress

the Vuepress dev server is not working just when i tried it by yarn. That server give me massive errors. but when i tried same thing by npm, there was no problem. What's wrong with my yarn? or vuepress? or windows?

my system information:

- Windows 10 64bit
- npm v6.13.4
- yarn v1.12.1
- vuepress v1.2.0

below is my steps for trying to make yarn-vuepress dev server

```
$mkdir dir-name

$cd dir-name

$yarn init -y
$yarn install
$yarn add vuepress -D
```

====edit package.json file==== 
add these:

```
"scripts":{
"dev:docs":"vuepress dev docs"
"build:docs":"vuepress build docs"
}
```

==============================

make "\docs" folder and "README.md" file.

==============================
again at terminal,

```
$yarn dev:docs
```

.
.
.
Client building...
.
.
.

`>VuePress dev server listening at http://localhost:8080/`

but in that page, always i see this on console:
[bug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX5NK.png)

What can i do for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I retried
`yarn dev`

after i
`npm i`
where 'package.json' file is,

and success to run Yarn dev server!